# remove similar (redundant) strings from Arraylist

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I'm trying to remove similar strings from an ArrayList but I'm getting this error:

```
 CurrentModificationException
```

and here is my method where I pass my original arrayList (old) and get a new list without redundant strings.

```
ArrayList<String> removeRed(ArrayList<String> old) throws IOException
{       

    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int i=0; i< old.size(); i++)
    {
        if(newList.size() < 1)
        {
            newList.add(old.get(0));

        } else{

            for(Iterator<String> iterator = newList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

                while(iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    if(!ChopMD((String) iterator.next()).equals(ChopMD(old.get(i))))
                    {
                        newList.add(old.get(i));
                        Log.e("new algo", "" + old.get(i) );
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }}
```

Note that my ChopMD() returns a particular string and it works fine. 
It works fine for the first few strings, this it throws that exception. Any suggestion to resolve this issue would be appreciated it. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to change your data model such that you are using a custom object that knows how to make these equals comparisons on itself?  That way you could even store the ID and the String in separate member variables, making comparisons faster since you don't have to do string mangling on every iteration.  Your custom object could still have a `toString()` method that puts it back into your `ID,String` format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no problems with using the standard library (always preferable, why reinvent the wheel) try

```
List<String> uniques = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(oldList));
```

The `HashSet` will only contain unique strings and the `ArrayList` constructor takes any `Collection` (including a `HashSet`) to build a list from.

Judging from your comments it seems like you are trying to implement an [Associative Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) with unique keys using an ArrayList. The better approach is to use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation like HashMap to pair IDs with their associated Strings.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "This string corresponds to ID=1");
map.put(3, "Donald Ducks Nephews");
map.put(7, "Is a Prime");
```

Then to get a value associated with an ID:

```
int key = someObject.getID();
String value = map.get(key);
```

All the Map implementations use unique keys so there is no need for you to check for redundant IDs, if you try to add a new (key,value) pair the value associated with the ID will be replaced if the map contains the key.

```
map.put(1, "New String");
String s = map.get(1); //s will no longer be "This string corresponds to ID=1"
```

If you don't want this behavior you have the choice of either subclassing one of the Map implementations to ignore `.put(key, value)` if the map contains `key,value` or delegating `.put(key,value)` to some other class.

**Subclassing:**

```
public class UniqueValueHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K, V>{
@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (containsKey(key))
        return null;
    return super.put(key, value);
}
```

**Delegating**

```
 public class SomeClass {
    private Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    // ...stuff this class does

    public String put(int key, String value) {
        if (map.containsKey(key))
            return null;
        return map.put(key, value);
    }

    // ...more stuff this class does
 }
```

Delegation is the better approach, notice how you can change the map implementation (using maybe a TreeMap instead of HashMap) without introducing a new class where you override the `.put(key,value)` of TreeMap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @arynaq . This doesn't work exactly as I need because in the arrayList I've got strings formatted as `("ID,String")` and that's why I am using `ChopMD()` to return a string without the ID in order to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate much easier by this

```
    for (String oldString : old){
        for (String newString : newList){

        }
    }
```

Also you can use Set to have unique strings

```
    Set<String> newList = new HashSet<String>();
```

Your error is because you are changing the list WHILE it is still iterated.

Comment: Thanks @libik . Please look into my comment on arynaq's.